# How to make it so that parent creates child, exits before the child completes, then the orphan is re-parented by init?

Tags: shell, process, c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main ()
{
  pid_t child_pid;

  child_pid = fork ();
  // parent process
  if (child_pid > 0) {
    printf("\n(parent): Parent's PID : %d\n",getpid());
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep (10);
    printf("\n(parent): Parent exits\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    /*int returnStatus;
    waitpid(child_pid, &returnStatus, 0);
    if (returnStatus == 0)  // Verify child process is terminated.
    {
       printf("The child process terminated normally.");
                         sleep(10);
    }*/
  }
  // child process
  else {
    printf("\n(child): Child's PID : %d\n",getpid());
    printf("\n(child): Child's Parent ID : %d\n",getppid());
    printf("\n(child): Child exits and becomes and zombie while parent 
sleeps.\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    exit (0);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This is what I have so far using Vim under Unix. How do I edit modify this piece so that when the parent creates the child, it exits before the child is completed, in which it turns into an orphan; then it gets re-parented and the child exits?

I know I'm supposed to use `sleep(value)` to delay the processes, but I'm unsure and confused as to what I'm delaying so that the orphan can be re-parented after the initial parents leaves.

Comment: If a child's parent terminates before the child terminates, by default the child automatically gets reparented to init.

Answer (score 1):

`sleep` is a kluge that may not work if the system is busy or otherwise may require a needlessly long delay. A better approach is to communicate between the parent and child such that the child blocks until the parent responds or in this case goes away. This can be done with a pipe and a blocking `read` in the child process that blocks until the parent (some time later...) does go away.

```
#include <err.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char ch;
    int fd[2];
    pid_t pid;
    ssize_t ret;

    pipe(fd);

    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        err(1, "fork failed");
    } else if (pid == 0) { /* child */
        close(fd[1]);
        warnx("child  %d start", getpid());
        // block until parent goes away
        ret = read(fd[0], &ch, 1);
        warnx("child  %d parent gone", getpid());
    } else { /* parent */
        // simulate system being slow
        sleep(3);
    }
    return 0;
}
```